# In "The Possession of Hannah Grace" what's the name of the work that Megan did in the morgue?

Tags: the-possession-of-hannah-grace

Was she a mortuary assistant? A medical examiner? A coroner? What kind of career includes taking pictures of the deceased and their fingerprints?

Comment: For the record, those three words appear in various movie reviews, none from an actor/director source; I watched a couple interviews of the actors and they all say "Megan works at the morgue". There's surely an actual job position, but I think they have no idea what it is :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [blurb](https://www.possessionofhannahgrace.movie/synopsis/) (and various interviews) for the film seem *intentionally vague*. She's described as "working the graveyard shift" but no specific role or job title are mentioned.

> A shocking exorcism spirals out of control, claiming the life of a young woman. Months later, **Megan Reed (Shay Mitchell) is working the graveyard shift in the morgue** when she takes delivery of a disfigured cadaver.

Megan's role most closely matches that of a [Mortuary Assistant/Mortuary Technician](https://nationalcareersservice.direct.gov.uk/job-profiles/anatomical-pathology-technician) but as you've noted, things like fingerprint-taking and basic medical examination would generally be done by a qualified Coroner or M.E. Presumably the fact that she has police experience means that the morgue is happy that she can perform those basic duties without the Coroner in attendance and be trusted to relay any untoward findings to the police without disturbing any forensic evidence.

---

For the record, the film was partially [based on the true story](https://www.bustle.com/p/is-the-possession-of-hannah-grace-based-on-a-true-story-the-movie-has-some-freaky-real-life-inspirations-13176478) of a young lady who was given a [Community Service sentence in a local morgue in Los Angeles](https://losangeles.cbslocal.com/2011/10/21/lohan-to-perform-community-service-at-la-county-morgue/). Those sentences typically involve porter work, janitorial duties and supporting the mortuary staff.